# Making a free virtual number (without paying)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot for groups with more than 5000 members.
I know that the bots made with Iranian phone numbers in Bot Father do not work in groups with more than 5,000 members, so we need Iranians to use the virtual numbers of countries such as Russia and the United States to use such bots. How can I make a free virtual number (without paying) countries like Russia and Russia?
Please, if you know a site or software or application that can be used to create a virtual number for making a telegram account without paying the money.

Comment: Sorry, but we do not give recommendations for services or software to use.

Comment: Someone know some service has free quota, but StackOverflow's ToS don't let me do it like advertising

Comment: @Sean This is a my gmail.address:sajjad.hajian2233@gmail.com

Comment: please your answer send to my gmail.

Comment: Try asking here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BadBoy No. Read rule